# Importing Bazel Build Tensorflow

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, clion

I'm trying to import the tensorflow project into the CLion IDE (on Linux) so that I can run various cc tests for example [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/constant_folding_test.cc).

I've built tensorflow from source using Bazel following the instructions from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) . Now, I'm trying to import the bazel project into the CLion IDE by following the steps listed [here](https://ij.bazel.build/docs/import-project.html).

I'm not able to select an initial project view file of `.bazelproject` type since it does not exist in my `tensorflow` directory.

Am I missing something or is there another way so that I can run tensorflow test files on my ide?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are attempting to do. What test files do you want to run? Assuming you want to use the c bindings in Tensorflow? Since you are using CLion?

Comment: I'm trying to modify tf source code and I notice many *_test.cc files, like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/constant_folding_test.cc) for example. I want to test such files with the help of CLion.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense. Did you install the CLion Bazel plugin [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9554-bazel) and followed the instructions [here](https://ij.bazel.build/docs/bazel-plugin.html). There is a workspace.bzl file in the root of the TF repository. If this doesn't get you going let me know and I will post a detailed step by step instructions.

Comment: yes, I installed the plugin by going into the Settings > Plugins > Install > Browse Repositories of IDE.  Then, I'm trying to import the project following the link [here] (https://ij.bazel.build/docs/import-project.html) , but am unable to get the built tensorflow project into CLion.

Comment: I do see a workspace.bzl file in tensorflow/tensorflow directory. But, I'm not sure where and how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the Tensorflow project is no different than any other Bazel Project. It works fine for me when I try the following:

1. Install the Bazel plugin by going to configure -> Plugins -> and searching for Bazel. Install the following plugin:

[image]

2. Once installed restart CLion
3. Once restarted click on the open project option in the load screen:

[image]

4. This will open and import the tensorflow project with build settings. You can see from this image that the bazel configuration and settings are imported correctly:

[image]

**Note:** Bazel builds the entire tensorflow project into an installable python package. If you are purely interested in compiling it for C/C++ then I suggest you look at how to build and use the [C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide) as building the entire project for every edit you make will age you very quickly.

**Recommendation:** If you just want to run the test files then install Tensorflow and simply execute the test files like you would run any program with cpp source files.

Comment: Thank you so much Isak, I will try doing this.